# select option value and assigning value to var (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Edit: I've changed the code as follows. Now none of the code seems to work. (Even my the code that did work and I didn't share with you.)

```
function berekeningAflostabel() {
var zaaksoortMsnp;
var AflostabelPerMaand;

document.getElementById("fldZaakSoortMsnp").addEventListener("change",     function () {
  AflostabelPerMaand = this.value;

  if(AflostabelPerMaand == 1) {
    zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst1";
  }
  if(AflostabelPerMaand == 2) {
    zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst2";
  }
  if(AflostabelPerMaand == 3) {
    zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst3";
  }
  if(AflostabelPerMaand == 4) {
    zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst4";
  }
  if(AflostabelPerMaand == 5) {
    zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst5";
  }
  if(AflostabelPerMaand == 6) {
    zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst6";
  }

  document.getElementById("fldMinimaleAfloswaardePerMaand").value = zaaksoortMsnp;
  }
}

var eventZaaksoortMsnp = document.getElementById("fldZaakSoortMsnp");
eventZaaksoortMsnp.addEventListener("change", berekeningAflostabel);
```

Comment: Hint : `=`  vs  `==`.

Comment: You're not calling the function in the code you provided!

Comment: As an optimisation just set the value to be `0x` (x is the number) or at least remove all the `if`s and do this: `var AflostabelPerMaand = '0' + zaaksoortMsnp.value;`!

Comment: The 01, 02 etc. values for AflostabelPerMaand is a dummy text. If it works, I'll replace them with currency values.

Comment: @NielsSanders Then look at the answer bellow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to get the selected option's value inside the `change` listener then you should use: `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`

You need to apply the `change` listener only once. The last two line are unnecessary.

The following code should work:

```js
function berekeningAflostabel() {
  var zaaksoortMsnp;
  var AflostabelPerMaand;

  document.getElementById("fldZaakSoortMsnp").addEventListener("change", function() {
    AflostabelPerMaand = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    if(AflostabelPerMaand == 1) {
      zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst1";
    }
    if(AflostabelPerMaand == 2) {
      zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst2";
    }
    if(AflostabelPerMaand == 3) {
      zaaksoortMsnp = "Tekst3";
    }

    document.getElementById("fldMinimaleAfloswaardePerMaand").value = zaaksoortMsnp;
  });
}

berekeningAflostabel();
```

```html
<select id="fldZaakSoortMsnp">
  <option value="1">teszt</option>
  <option value="2">teszt</option>
  <option value="3">teszt</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="fldMinimaleAfloswaardePerMaand">
```

Comment: The `if`s are unnecessary in the first place!

Comment: It's seems that OP is looking for this answer not mine!

Comment: But you should use `==` not `===` as they're not of the same type (one is a string , the other is a number)!

Comment: I've edited my original message. (Couldn't add another message with new code.) If you'd like to react, that'll be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change your function to this

```
function () {
    var AflostabelPerMaand = '0' + this.value;
    document.getElementById("fldMinimaleAfloswaardePerMaand").value = AflostabelPerMaand;
}
```

Comment: "The 01, 02 etc. values for AflostabelPerMaand is a dummy text."